# Embedded ActiveMQ connection taking a long time to shutdown

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using Camel with embedded ActiveMQ for some functional tests. But after the tests have run, ActiveMQ is having trouble shutting down, and I see logs like this:

```
2022-01-31 19:12:34,873 [MQ ShutdownHook] INFO  BrokerService                  - Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.9 (localhost, ID:8dc9dbba2775-37769-1643655318556-0:2) is shutting down
...
2022-01-31 19:12:34,875 [MQ ShutdownHook] INFO  TransportConnector             - Connector tcp://localhost:0 stopped
2022-01-31 19:12:35,052 [m://localhost#4] INFO  PooledConnectionFactory        - Expiring connection ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:8dc9dbba2775-37769-1643655318556-4:3,clientId=ID:8dc9dbba2775-37769-1643655318556-3:2,started=false} on IOException: peer (vm://localhost#5) stopped.
...
2022-01-31 19:12:35,053 [MQ ShutdownHook] INFO  BrokerService                  - Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.9 (localhost, ID:8dc9dbba2775-37769-1643655318556-0:19) is shutdown
2022-01-31 19:12:40,052 [MQ ShutdownHook] INFO  TransportConnection            - The connection to 'vm://localhost#12' is taking a long time to shutdown.
2022-01-31 19:12:45,052 [MQ ShutdownHook] INFO  TransportConnection            - The connection to 'vm://localhost#12' is taking a long time to shutdown.
2022-01-31 19:12:50,053 [MQ ShutdownHook] INFO  TransportConnection            - The connection to 'vm://localhost#12' is taking a long time to shutdown.
```

A connection shutdown is failing and keeps repeating that last message.

The config is done programmatically for the tests :

```
private static void addActiveMqComponent()
{
    if ( FunctionalTestFramework.framework().context().getComponent("activemq2") == null)
    {
        JmsConfiguration jmsConfig = new JmsConfiguration();
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost:61616?broker.persistent=false");
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(1000);
        redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(1000);
        redeliveryPolicy.setBackOffMultiplier(3.5);
        redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(-1);
        connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
        jmsConfig.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory );
        transactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        jmsConfig.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        ActiveMQComponent activeMqComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
        activeMqComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfig);
        activeMqComponent.setTransacted(true);
        activeMqComponent.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_CONSUMER");
        FunctionalTestFramework.framework().context().addComponent("activemq2", activeMqComponent);
    }
}
```

I've seen some other threads suggesting to set `useShutdownHook="false"` but it only applies when they're explicitly triggering shutdown (`broker.stop()`) which I'm not doing. And I'm not finding much else on this specific problem.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: I would turn on debug logging on the TransportConnection to see what is happening in the stopping the connection

Comment: What happens if you set the `transacted` to `false`?  I'm thinking  that the session can not be closed if there is an active transaction pending.  Just so you know, if you set `transacted` to `true`, the cache level will be set to `NONE`, so your `CACHE_CONSUMER` is being ignored.